# Passing a param id in ASP.NET CORE MVC? Getting NULL id

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

When passing paramater cartId to action method Index() and going to route /cart/{cartId} so /cart/1 - cartId is always null!

I have a Action Method in CartController.cs

```
   public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int? cartId)

{
    if(cartId == null)
        Cart = _cartsService.GetCartById(1);


    if (!cartId.HasValue)
        return Content("Cart id with given id not found!");


    // Model bind to the Cart of MockCartRepository (entity type?)
    Cart = _cartsService.GetCartById(cartId.Value);
    if (Cart == null)
        return Content("Cart not found in database");

    return View(Cart);
}
```

I have a view called index.cshtml

```
@model eComStore.Models.Cart

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Cart";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h2 class="display-4">My Cart Id @Model.cartId</h2>
    @foreach (var product in Model.ProductsInCart)
    {
        <h5>Product Id @product.ProductId</h5>
        <h5>Product Qty @product.qty</h5>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
    }
</div>
```

**When DEBUGGING: Going to https://localhost:44308/Cart/1  I get a null value in cartId**

**Is there a difference in how param is passed in ASP.NET CORE RAZOR PAGES vs MVC?**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: for those voting the question down, it would be helpful to the OP for you to let them know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you configured the MapControllerRoute in the Startup.cs as the following ?

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

You may have to change id with cartId or change

```
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int? id)
```

The it's is accessible to the route Cart/Index/1.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1

**EDIT**

```
endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "Cart",
                    "Cart/{cartId}",
                    new { controller = "Cart", action = "Index" }
                );
```

And

```
public IActionResult Index([FromRoute] int? cartId)
```

Then it will be accessible with Cart/1

Comment: So I have to define a param called id, ok. But say I want to use cartId as a seperate param in Startup.cs, is this how you'd do it?     endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "cart",
                    pattern: "cart/{*Index}/cartId",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Cart", action = "Index" });

Comment: Hello, try to add
 endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    "Cart",
                    "Cart/{cartId}",
                    new { controller = "Cart", action = "Index" }
                );

Comment: Thanks. Although it seems to work even without [FromRoute].. Is this attribute even used in ASP.NET CORE MVC or is it part of the ASP.NET CORE WEB API? any idea

Answer (score 0):

You probbaly want to do something like this

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index([FromQuery] int cartId)
{
    // Your code here
}
```

or

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("/yourroutehere/{id:int}")]
public IActionResult Index([FromQuery] int cartId)
{
    // Your code here
```

Personally I wouldnt make your int a nullable item, but this should make it work for you

Comment: I was confused between "conventional" vs "Attribute Routing"? As in when do use either. Is there a common practice going with attribute routing in standard mvc app or is it more popular with asp core APIs?

Comment: I suspect its more popular with .Net Core and seems to be the convention that I have naturally fallen into really with work I've been doing over the years and more so with .Net core.  There is no requirement to set anything up and you would typically have a route attribute(s) at controller level too.